# Small integer program seem to be extremely slow

Tags: c#, or-tools

I have a number of remaining capacities of different delivery time slots. Reaching capacity 0 or below makes a time slot sold out.
I have a fixed number of reservations which should be distributed among the time slots in some way that keeps most slots open (above 0) and dont result in <0 capacity. This will happen extremely often if taken into use.. like multiple times a second.

Now my model works as far as my tests so far shows, however I must ensure a really good performance.. its not acceptable to take 1 second to compute. I also always have a very limited number of time slots to work with so its not like the model will sometimes gets thousands of variables.

My question is.. is there a particular reason why my sample code below is so insanely slow. I dont feel it have a lot of variables. Anything I can do or must I consider using something besides integer programming.

Pay in mind that this sample code just distributes a single reservationAmount among all slots. Normally there would be many different reservationAmount numbers mapped to a subset of the time slots. Its because of this that I can't just make an algorithm that distributes reservations into slots with highest remaining capacity as overlapping could course such an algorithm to reserve time slots that others would be dependent on with their given reservationAmount in order to get best distribution.

```cs
var model = new CpModel();
var capacities = new int[] { 2, 3, 6, 9, 12, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 6, 9, 12, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 6, 9, 12, 5, 2, 7 };
capacities = capacities.Take(capacities.Count()).ToArray();
var reservationAmount = capacities.Sum() - 8;
var remainingCapacityExpressions = new List<LinearExpr>();
var reservationVars = new List<IntVar>();
for (var index = 0; index < capacities.Length; index++) {
  var resVar = model.NewIntVar(0, int.MaxValue, $"res_{index}");
  reservationVars.Add(resVar);

  var remainingCapacityExpression = capacities[index] - resVar;
  remainingCapacityExpressions.Add(remainingCapacityExpression);
}

model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(reservationVars) == reservationAmount);

var lowestRemainingCapacityInPairsVars = new List<IntVar>();
for (var index = 0; index < capacities.Length; index++) {
  for (var index2 = index + 1; index2 < capacities.Length; index2++) {
    var remainingCapacityPairA = remainingCapacityExpressions[index];
    var remainingCapacityPairB = remainingCapacityExpressions[index2];

    var minVar = model.NewIntVar(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, $"h_{index}_{index2}");

    // Objective maximization will force all minVar to be as high as allowed
    model.Add(minVar <= remainingCapacityPairA);
    model.Add(minVar <= remainingCapacityPairB);    

    lowestRemainingCapacityInPairsVars.Add(minVar);
  }
}

model.AddDecisionStrategy(
  lowestRemainingCapacityInPairsVars,
  DecisionStrategyProto.Types.VariableSelectionStrategy.ChooseHighestMax,
  DecisionStrategyProto.Types.DomainReductionStrategy.SelectMaxValue);

model.Maximize(LinearExpr.Sum(lowestRemainingCapacityInPairsVars));

// Creates a solver and solves the model.
var solver = new CpSolver();
var status = solver.Solve(model);
```

Comment: Some nitpicking: 1) You talk about integer-programming, but use a NOT-integer-programming solver. This is confusing and complicates all kind of reasoning (like a simplified one: optimization / non-feasibility problems + CP / SAT = ouch -> it's so "ouch", that there are multiple different approaches to that in CP-SAT solver). 2) You describe some real-time (or online task) and want to guarantee a time-limit, but use exponential-time worst-case approaches.This is troublesome, even in theory! 3) Instead of describing the model/solver-behaviour, you are forcing us to read and run that code...

Comment: 1) i guess cp sat means i am using a constraint programming solver.. i just said integer programming because i thought it was the right term when dealing with problems involving integers.. 2) right.. my biggest concern is that loop causing an exponential amount of more constraints and variables and perhaps my problem might not be easy to express as i cant see how else to solve it with linear programming.. 3) i wrote that code specifically for this forum to show exactly what i am doing in a short format rather than some long explanation, but i will write a better description :)

Comment: Can you try reducing the domains of the integer variables (0 .. max_capacity) instead of (int_min, int_max) ?

Comment: It didnt help, but I think i will have to look towards some traditional algorithmic approach rather than this stuff.. lp is a cool tech but doesnt seem applicable to solve my issue in reasable time... i have tried a lot of ideas.. Nontheless i appreciate the help and knowledge you both tried to provide :)